# WebBrowser cant open Instagram c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

when i put [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/)'s address in my WebBrowser object, on loading of program, it just shows a blank white page, and nothing else, where is problem?!
first i think it should be cause WebBrowser using IE, but IE(ver.11) loads [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/) successfully .

**UPDATE:**
this is the code which i use:

```
            this.webB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 17);
            this.webB.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            this.webB.Name = "webB";
            this.webB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(642, 324);
            this.webB.TabIndex = 1;
            this.webB.Url = new System.Uri("https://www.instagram.com/", System.UriKind.Absolute);
            this.webB.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.webB_DocumentCompleted);
            this.webB.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: Could you possibly show the `url` you're using - or some code. Please take some time to read up on how to ask questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AidenStrydom there is no code, cause i putted the link (https://www.instagram.com/) in URL part of WebBrowser's properties.

Comment: @AidenStrydom i added the code which written by vs too

Comment: if i put www.Google.com it works, but have problem with Instagram!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :). This code is useful for loading urls(ex:Instagram) and download the source code of the appropriate page.

```css
protected void LoadUrl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = txtUrl.Text.Trim();
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
     {
        using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
        {
            browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            browser.AllowNavigation = true;
            browser.Navigate(url);
            browser.Width = 1024;
            browser.Height = 768;
            browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentCompleted);
            while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
 
private void DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    string sourcecode=browser.documentText;
}
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work for me ,it pass me same result and a blank page